# login loop 19.04 works wayland but not x

Tags: login, 19.04

19.04 ubuntu login suddenly stopped working today after small upgrade. 
I can login fine with Wayland (whatever that is) but doesn't solve my problem as I need X to run vmware player.

running sudo startx gives

```
xauth:  file /home/tim/.Xauthority does not exist

X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-143-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux tim-XPS-15-9570 5.0.0-21-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 13:27:33 UTC 2019 x86_64
```

Kernel command line:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-21-generic root=UUID=91c0547f-e260-419d-b23c-fdbb6995cf59 ro quiet splash pcie_port_pm=off acpi_backlight=none acpi_osi=Linux "acpi_osi=Windows 2009" nouveau.noaccel=1 rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau nouveau.modeset=0 vt.handoff=1
```

no .xerrors
nothing in syslog that looks like a crash
I'm running on a notebook and same result with or without plugged in external monitors.
I tried installing gnome stuff and can log in as gnome but not gnome on Xorg

running dell xps 15, single-boot
Any more suggestions or should I just give up and try re-installing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not a definitive answer to may own question - I gave up and reinstalled. However, while reinstalling, I reinstalled the touchpad-indicator utility at some point in the process. This disabled my wifi. Removing it re-enabled my wifi. I didn't investigate thoroughly but I suspect the login loop might have been caused by failure in touchpad-indicator which may have some compatibility issues with very latest updates to 19.04. But this is just a conjecture.